# Bypassing SSL certificate in React native Android app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Can anybody suggest how to bypass or deal with the SSLHandshakeException while working on React Native Android app?

In iOS, we are able to do so by setting TSL flas as TRUE in info.plist file.

FYI, the server's certificate seems valid when we try to access any of its web service in a browser.

Comment: Having the same issue, were you able to figure it out @not_dying?

Comment: Have the same issue too. Any knows the answer?